# Why is Flux.fromIterable() return in RestController coming back as one concatenated string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Rest Conotroller that returns a `Flux<String>`, but when i try to collect that into a list, it is one item of all the strings concatenated. how can I get it as an actual list?

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController
{
    @GetMapping( "/getflux" )
    public Flux<String> getFlux()
    {
        return Flux.fromIterable(
            Arrays.asList(
                "String 1", 
                "String 2"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Calling the controller:

```
//This returns as a list of one item: "String 1String 2
List<String> response = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl( "http://localhost:" + port + "/" )
    .build()
    .get()
    .uri( "/getflux" )
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux( String.class )
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

How do I get the actual list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it appears this is a Spring bug that is marked as "working as intended".

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20807

> This is expected behavior. By default byte arrays, byte buffers, and String are treated as low level content (serialized output) and is rendered as is. In fact the Flux is streamed with each string written and flushed immediately.
>
> The Jackson encoder explicitly backs out for element type String. I realize that String and an array of String's can be rendered as JSON but there are two ways to treat String content and this is what we've chosen by default.

The only solution is to never return a `Flux<String>` but instead to return a list of some wrapper class you make. This would still allow using `Flux` and back pressure, and Spring properly handles such complex Objects.

The below works perfectly:

```
@GetMapping("/getflux")
public Flux<List<StringWrapper>> getFlux() {
    return Flux.fromIterable(
        Arrays.asList(
            new StringWrapper( "String 1" ),
            new StringWrapper( "String 2" )

        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a problem with `List<String>` deserialization (f.e., `List<Integer>` and many other types work well). I tried to tune Jackson's ObjectMapper configuration but failed. Maybe you should try it yourself too or even raise the issue to Jackson Github repo about it.

As a workaround, you can return `Mono<List<String>>` from the controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/getflux")
public Mono<List<String>> getFlux() {
    return Flux.fromIterable(
            Arrays.asList(
                    "String 1",
                    "String 2"

            )
    ).collectList();
}
```

, and call it like this:

```
List<String> block = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + 8080 + "/")
    .build()
    .get()
    .uri("/getflux")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
    })
    .block();
```

The result is `["String 1","String 2"]`. The same would be returned by calling the controller method directly from a web browser/curl/etc.

Comment: Seems to be a Spring bug that they claim is "as intended": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13020